# How to split the elements of a text file in C++

Tags: c++, file, split

i have a text file called builders.txt that contains some data

```
Reliable Rover:70:1.
Sloppy Simon:20:4.
Technical Tom:90:3.
```

Within my main file i have a function declaration related to this specific text file

```
void Builder() {

std:string name;
int ability;
int variability;

}
```

this is my read file function

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string inputFile1 = "Builders.txt";
std::string inputFile2 = "Parts.txt";
std::string inputFile3 = "Customers.txt";
std::string outputFile = "output.txt";
std::string input;

void readFile(std::string const& inputFile1, std::string const& inputFile2, std::string const& inputFile3,
              std::vector<std::string>& lines) //function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
{
   std::ifstream file1(inputFile1);
   std::ifstream file2(inputFile2);
   std::ifstream file3(inputFile3);
   std::string line;

   while(std::getline(file1, line)) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);

   }

     while(std::getline(file2, line)) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);
   }

     while(std::getline(file3, line)) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);
   }

}
```

This is my attempt

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;

std::string inputFile1 = "Builders.txt";
std::istringstream newStream(inputFile1);
std::string input;

void readFile(std::string const& newStream,std::vector<std::string>& lines) 
{
   std::ifstream file1(newStream);
   std::string line;

   while(std::getline(file1, line,":")) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);
      }
```

When i run this code i recieve the error "no instance of overload function getline"

My question is given the text file how can i split the text file so that, for example, Reliable Rover is the name, 70 is the ability and 1 is the variability for the 1st record. Another example would be Sloppy Simon being the name, 20 being the ability and 4 being variaiblity.  If the question is to vague or requires futher details please let me know

Thankyou

Comment: You have to show us what you have tried, and where you have failed, in order to help you.

Comment: Read a line using `std::getline` into a `std::stringstream`. Read an value using `std::stringstream` with `':'` as delimiter.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ive included my readFile Function. Do i need to modify it?

Comment: Why do you store the lines? Read a line, split it and store the values.

Comment: @ThomasSablik what line are you referring to?

Comment: Why do you store all lines in `std::vector<std::string> lines;` with `lines.push_back(line);`? Split the lines in the `while` loop and store the values.

Comment: @ThomasSablik it acts like a place holder function if that makes sense? Its there until i figure how to split it into the appropriate values i need.

Comment: It makes no sense. There are multiple ways to split a string. I described one way in my comments. Another way is described in the answer.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ive made an attempt at doing what you sugguested that holds errors. Ive updated my question

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Please see my updated question for the attempt made.

Comment: I wrote _Read a line using `std::getline` into a `std::stringstream`._ That means: read a line and initialize a `std::stringstream` with it. Now read from the `std::stringstream` with `std::getline` and use `':'` as delimiter.

Comment: So i need to read each line one by one?

Comment: There are many approaches for this problem. My solution is to read the file line by line, create a stringstream from each line and read each element from the stringstream.

Comment: @ThomasSablik my attempt I've posted is my understanding of that solution. Apologies im new to c++

Comment: Currently I'm not sure if you're trolling me. _"create a stringstream from each line"_ where does this happen in your attempt?

Answer (score 2):

As *@thomas-sablik* mentioned, a simple solution is to read the file line by line and read each element from the line:

```
std::ifstream f("builder.txt");
std::string line;

// read each line
while (std::getline(f, line)) {

    std::string token;
    std::istringstream ss(line);

    // then read each element by delimiter
    while (std::getline(ss, token, ':'))
      std::cout << token << std::endl;

  }
```

don't forget to include **sstream** for using stringstreams.

**Note:** refer to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), third parameter of `std::getline` is *delim* and is a character but you pass it as a string. So change:

```
while(std::getline(file1, line,":"))
```

to:

```
while(std::getline(file1, line,':'))
```

Comment: Would you do the same to treat each new line as a new record?

Comment: Actually this code reads each line of the file then splits line elements by colon, you can change the second `while` to change the behavior as you want.

Comment: would it be possible to split the file at the full stop, and then split it again at the colon?

Comment: yeah, just replace the first `std::getline` with `std::getline(f, line, '.')`

Comment: according to your `builders.txt` file, in this case each line splits to: the text before the dot and a `\n`. you can ignore that `\n` by an `if` statement :)

Comment: So i dont have to split the record twice?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive approach I came up with:

```
std::string name;
int ability;
int variability;

char read;
while (ifs >> read) { // read until the end of the file
    // adding read into name
    while (read != ':') {
        name += read;
        ifs >> read;
    }

    ifs >> ability;
    ifs >> read; // Remove ':'
    ifs >> variability;
    ifs >> read; // Remove '.'

    // Code to deal with the three variables

    name = "";
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think is better using `getline` function specificity `:` as separator

Comment: Yeah that probably would work better. I don't use getline a lot so I don't know it has that feature